# Sorting specified rows in a matrix by the first column in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a character matrix *mtr* of *n* rows and 3 columns.

I have a numeric vector *nmb* with some numbers, for example, 4,5,6

I want to sort only the rows of *mtr*, the numbers of which are contained by *nmb*, by the first column of my matrix.

So in my case I want to leave my matrix untouched except for rows 4,5,6 which I would like to be sorted by the first column and, of course, written back into my matrix *mtr*.

How could I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
mtr[nmb,] <- mtr[order(mtr[nmb,1]),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it

```
mtr[nmb,] <- mtr[nmb,][order(mtr[nmb,1]),]
```

An example:

```
nmb <- 4:6
mtr <- matrix(30:1, ncol=3)

> mtr
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   20   10
[2,]   29   19    9
[3,]   28   18    8
[4,]   27   17    7
[5,]   26   16    6
[6,]   25   15    5
[7,]   24   14    4
[8,]   23   13    3
[9,]   22   12    2
[10,]   21   11    1

> mtr[nmb,] <- mtr[nmb,][order(mtr[nmb,1]),]

> mtr
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   20   10
[2,]   29   19    9
[3,]   28   18    8
[4,]   25   15    5   <-
[5,]   26   16    6   <- sorted
[6,]   27   17    7   <-
[7,]   24   14    4
[8,]   23   13    3
[9,]   22   12    2
[10,]   21   11    1
```